# Creating a transparent cylinder

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I'm trying to create a transparent cylinder.  I've tried setting transparent, opacity, etc., but can't seem to get it to work.  Is there any way to do this?  Do I need to load a dummy texture with an alpha channel?  Is there a simpler way?

```
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe: true});
material.transparent = true;
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(4, 4, 50, 8, 1, true), material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Update:  I've changed the code to the following, but it seems wrong to use ShaderMaterial in this way.  But it works...

```
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({wireframe: true, transparent: true});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(4, 4, 50, 8, 1, true), material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Update:  Here are the images.

- I can't add the images properly or add links, since I need a reputation of 11, and only have 10, so I've added broken links instead.  Add 'h' in front of each url.

ttp://img692.imageshack.us/img692/6412/shadermaterial.png
Using ShaderMaterial you see the rectangular grey Sprite surrounded by a transparent cylinder.

http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/3988/opacity00.png
Using MeshBasicMaterial with Opacity 0.0.

http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/6087/opacity05.png
Using MeshBasicMaterial with Opacity 0.5.

http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/8043/opacity10.png
Using MeshBasicMaterial with Opacity 1.0.

Answer (score 6):

Shouldn't it be this instead?

```
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { wireframe: true, opacity: 0.5 } );
```

Comment: I have something (a Sprite) inside the cylinder.  If I do the following, the Sprite no longer is visible, although the background is affected by the opacity.  If I change the opacity to 0.0 the Sprite is invisible, and 1.0 it's a white cylinder.
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { wireframe: false, opacity: 0.5 } );
    material.transparent = true;

Comment: Sure, I'll get those.  This is related to the following, where I can't seem to intersect a Sprite.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11511787/1518845

Comment: I've added links to the screenshots in the question.

Comment: In my case I had to do `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, opacity: 0.5, transparent: true } )`. Didn't work without `transparent: true`.